# FB.login() not calling callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the simple code for Facebook login button from JS SDK where I added Google Analytics code to see how many successful logins there are:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'a login', 'x', 'null');
FB.login(function(resp) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'a login callback', 'x', 'null');
    if (resp.authResponse) {
        testAPI(true, 1);
    } else {
        alert('Must be logged in with Facebook account!');
    }
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,user_photos'});
```

The results are surprising:

```
1.  a login             x   384 16.28%
2.  a login callback    x   361 15.31%
```

Basically for 23 times (that's 384-361) the callback function was not called. This happens will all subsequent JS API calls. I'm not posting the full code here but the results are:

```
1.  a login             x   441 15.96%
2.  a login callback    x   421 15.23%
3.  b testAPI 1         x   395 14.29%
4.  b testAPI callback  x   384 13.89%
```

So in testAPI function call to FB API an other 11 times the callback function is not called. This brings the total users from 441(pressing the button) to 384 who actually complete the flow. Off course some users do not authorize the app, so a slight drop is to be expected, but the missing callback calls do not seem ok with me.

Has anybody else experienced this ?

Comment: Have you verified the users aren't simply closing your page?

Comment: no, perhaps I should.

Comment: Seriously though, if you're logging something in both branches of an if/else block and seeing some missing, it's reasonable to assume neither branch is being triggered, which would happen if execution was stopped completely before returning (which AFAIK will happen if the window is closed)

Comment: ok, please write an answer so I can accept it